# Deleting a Row for a tableView with its corresponding Parse.com Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to delete a tableView row and its corresponding parse.com data at the same time. But I can't seem to get the data to reload and delete the tableView row. I CAN however, delete the data from parse when I click delete on the cell, but the app will crash. Upon restarting the app, the tableview row will have the correct current data. Here is how I am attempting to delete the row.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView beginUpdates];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{

    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    [user removeObject:[[user objectForKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"];
    [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {

            [user refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {


                    [[[[self.tracks objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"]mutableCopy]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

                    [tableView reloadData];
                    [tableView endUpdates];
                }
                else NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }];

        }
        else NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];


}
```

}

As you can see, I am removing the PFObject from Parse.com, and saving the changes. If the save is successful I refresh the data on my Parse Object. If that save is successful, the array's object is deleted and the corresponding row is deleted, then the tableView's data is reloaded. 
Apparently this is incorrect as I am getting this Error...

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'"

Comment: Holy crap, you do NOT write `[[[[self.tracks objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"]mutableCopy]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` in a single line. The most `[]` a line should contain is two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash happens because of this line:

```
[[[[self.tracks objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"]mutableCopy]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Which I *really* hate how it looks, so I'll format it:

```
NSDictionary *tracksDictionary = [self.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *favoriteTracks = [tracksDictionary objectForKey:@"favoritedTracksArray"];
NSMutableArray *mutableFavoriteTracks = [favoriteTracks mutableCopy];
[mutableFavoriteTracks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You're creating a copy of your array and deleting the object in that. This doesn't affect your original array/container which provides the data source.

Thus you're deleting a row in the table view, but not in the data source.

Instead of doing this, you should make `mutableFavoriteTracks` a property, this will represent the data source for your table view and deleting tracks from this array when needed.

Comment: Ya, I had to leave my computer for a few hours and I realized how stupid that line of code was. Sorry lmao, I'm a new developer still learning the ropes. I got it to work though, thanks a lot man.